# (Debian) Running two mail- and web- servers at the same time in different docker containers

Tags: nginx, debian, email-server, port, exim

I´ve setup a Debian Webserver with two docker containers:
 - a laradock container (laradock.io - Documentation availible at [laradock.io](https://www.laradock.io)).
 - a mailcow container ([mailcow.email](https://mailcow.email/) - Documentation availible [here](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/))

I setup the laradock container first, and at the moment, while running the services `caddy, mysql, php-fpm and workspace`, docker reserves following ports on my system (`lsof -i -n -P`):

```
COMMAND     PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 11641        root    4u  IPv6 354251      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 11848        root    4u  IPv6 355207      0t0  TCP *:2222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 12229        root    4u  IPv6 356964      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 12241        root    4u  IPv6 357019      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 13809        root    4u  IPv4 367743      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:19991 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 13837        root    4u  IPv4 367839      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:13306 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 13890        root    4u  IPv6 368035      0t0  TCP *:4190 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 13913        root    4u  IPv6 368092      0t0  TCP *:995 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 13949        root    4u  IPv6 368179      0t0  TCP *:993 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 13975        root    4u  IPv6 368244      0t0  TCP *:143 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 13989        root    4u  IPv6 368290      0t0  TCP *:110 (LISTEN)
```

When trying to run mailcat-dockerized with `debian-compose up -d` in the directory I installed all mailcut files in, I encouter following problems:

```
[...] Mailcat/NGINX: Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated [...]
[...] Mailcat/POSTFIX: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:25: bind: address already in use
```

When having a look at my other entries in `lsof -i -n -P`, there is a reason for this failure:

```
COMMAND     PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
exim4      3050 Debian-exim    3u  IPv4  17648      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:25 (LISTEN)
exim4      3050 Debian-exim    4u  IPv6  17653      0t0  TCP [::1]:25 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 12229        root    4u  IPv6 356964      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

The Debian pre-installed mailer `exim` reserved port 25 for listening on mails, and my laradock container with `caddy` (an nginx-like server with easier ssl) is (of course) using port 443.
In the Mailcat-config file I can change the port for it´s nginx server to a other port, and the smtp port too.
As far as I´m concerned, I still need `exim4`, so there´s no way I will remove it from my system. I need it so that I can send a mail everytime somebody successfully does an ssh logon on my system. I can change its port or the port mailcat uses for SMTP, but I am not sure how this will affect sending/receiving mails, especially when two mail-recipents are installed at the same time (exim and mailcow). I can´t send my ssh logon mail over mailcow, since it´s in a dockerized container.
I´ve set the hostname/FQDN for mailcow to mail.mydomain.com, which I thought would save me the hassle of having to change my port bindings for caddy/nginx, since my laradock-container with caddy is only listening to mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com , not mail.mydomain.com.
If I will have to change the ports of one of my services anyway, to which port should I change it (and should I change my caddy or nginx configuration - I´d take nginx, since caddy is serving my web content and therefore more important). How can I tell caddy to redirect all requests to mail.mydomain.com to nginx in a different container?

I´d be so happy about any answers at this point.

Comment: You need to make your wishes clear, so that you can assign ports correctly. Do you want email coming in from outside the system to be handled by the native exim, or by one of the containers? Same goes for incoming https traffic: where do you want it to be handled? If in a container, then assign port 443 to that container, and reconfigure the other container to forward a different port to the container. These are decisions only you can make.

Comment: @wurtel At the moment, I'd like that incoming mails go to my container, and that all mails (even ones that are sent by my system in bash files) are sent over this container, not exim, so I can remove exim.

Comment: @wurtel My http(s) Traffic should be split by which domain is requested. I'm thinking about a reverse proxy configuration here, but I'm not sure on how to implement it yet. When a person calls any subdomain except mail.mydomain.com, smtp.mydomain.com and imap.mydomain.com, the request should be handled by my Laradock container. All other requests (e.g. mail requests to mail., smtp. and imap.) should be handled by my Mailcat container.

Comment: @wurtel My idea is setting up nginx on my system, listening to Port 80 and 443. Then, somehow, detect the requested URL and redirect properly. I'm not sure on exactly how to accomplish this and how to target a specific nginx in a Docker container as the destination of my proxy. I'd have to redirect the request to a specific Port my Laradock / Mailcat nginx is listening to, I guess.